# Configure Apache 2.0 for multiple owa

Tags: apache-2.2, exchange

Let me see if I can explain this coherently:

We currently have Exchange 2003 and use Apache that sets in our dmz as a proxy for our OWA. 
We are now in the process of upgrading Exchange 03 to Exchange 2010 and plan a 
coexsistance. For a time, there will be some users on 03 and some on 2010 using OWA. I will be adding another ip address with and external dns record legacy.ourdomain.com to point to the 2003 exchange and change the webmail.ourdomain.com dns record to point to the new 2010 exchange server. There is also a cName in our internal dns records that points to the 03 exchange server (alias webmail  fqdn mail.ourdomain.com), so I am assuming I will need to change that dns record to point to the new 2010 exchange then create another cName for the 03 exchange with legacy.ourdomain.com

Now can anyone tell me what configuration changes I would need to make on our Apache server 
to allow for both webmails.

According to our ex admin: 
the server in the dmz is a windows 2003 and running apache and dns forwarders.
Basically external requests go to our dns servers they pass the traffic to the apache/dns server. It then forwards the traffic to internal IPs

there are 3 conf files that I have found with info pertaining to the webmail. an httpd-conf,
a httpd-ssl.conf, and a httpd-vhosts.conf. I can post some of the info from the files if I 
need to, to help me solve this. I have no experience with apache so any help or direction to any other helpful site would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Apache as a proxy for IIS, you should be in good shape. As I recall from our own Exchange 2003 to 2007 upgrade, the OWA for 2007 includes the 2003 site and will proxy users to the 2003 servers *internally*. So you'd point your Apache servers at the 2007 OWA installs, and then those IIS installs would further proxy your 2003-based users to the 2003 front-end servers.

It's a long chain, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you...I thought that is the way it should work but like I said I have no experience with apache. So I understatnd,  I will need to add the new ssl certs I get for exchange 2010 webmail cert and key to the apache, then edit the 3 conf files to point to the 2010 exchange server instead of the 03 exchange. If you think of anything else I need to expect please let me know. Again thank you for your reply it's very helpful.